# "The connection was refused by the host" error only with mobile data

Tags: android, mobile, network-programming, ip

I have a custom business application that is being used on about ten android phones. The server which serves the application is not mapped on a domain, but it is accessible directly with IP address. And everything is working fine for 3 or so months.

Now, one of the company decides to get a bigger phone - Alcatel One Touch 5020x. I set up the application and everything was working fine - the application was able to read and post data to the web service. But, I was testing it while on WiFi. They need to use it with mobile data, because people work on remote terrain.

When we switched to mobile data, application was unable to reach the server and this error is thrown: "The connection was refused by the host!"

Switching back to WiFi, everything is working fine.

A different phone on the same network doesn't have this problem - it is just this phone. What can be the problem?

Please help, I contacted the network's technical support, but they will need couple of days to respond.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, since domains are cheap, I decided to go the easy way and bought a .info domain which costs 3$ per year. I had to open my web app on port 80, since the same error occurs if I have port number in the URI (http://domain.info:9999 for example throws same exception).

I hope this helps someone in the future :)